# Counterfeit coin problem.

Tags: optimization

**Problem**

$N$ coins, $N-1$ equal coins and one heavier counterfiet coin.
With a balance beam given we want to find the counterfeit coin.
We have two different goals:

- minimise the expected number of weighings
- minimise the maximal number of required weighings

---

I have no idea on how to develop a search algorithm for each of the two goals, I hope someone can help me finding it!

Answer (score 1):

The full solution to this problem can be found in the book linked: http://www.scribd.com/doc/7360109/The-USSR-Olympiad-Problem-Book

It is Question 4 b) in the Introductory Problems (Page 7). The solution can be found in pages 84-86 of the book.

Comment: The cited source does not talk about minimizing the expected number of weighings.